# RGB color combinations

Tags: permutations, combinations

RGB colors are selected by 3 selectors: Red, Green, and Blue. Each of these can be between $0$ and $255$.

So (and I'm sure this is some kind of permutation but I can't put my finger on the actual math involved) I was wondering exactly how many choices this is, and what is the math that goes along with it.

[0-255],[0-255],[0-255]

EXs:

0,5,2

52,215,65

etc etc

Comment: Are you asking how many "colors" you can specify using 256 values per color channel?

Comment: There are $256^3$ possible choices, that is, $2^{24}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simply $$256 \cdot 256 \cdot 256 = 256^3=16777216$$

Edit: $256$, not $255$. Need to include $0$.

Comment: Be careful, though. Because the range for each color RGB is $[0,255]$, there are $256$ choices for each.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, I realised as soon as I posted

Comment: That's so interesting to me because a lot of color pickers make it so you can click to select, each of those little boxes have 16 million choices, and that's insane.